# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; using DENSE_RANK() on live server

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a simple API and while it works in my local xampp i get a syntax error on my live server.

```
SELECT name, DENSE_RANK() over ( order by countries.photo_profile) as countryrank FROM countries
```

This works perfectly on my local setup:
PHP version: 7.4.4
10.4.11-MariaDB

But not on my live server setup:
Tried PHP version: 7.4.11, 7.3, 7.2
DB: Percona 5.6.40-84.0

Error:

> Server error","debug":"SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access
> violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
> that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
> use near '( order by countries.photo_profile) as countryrankFROM
> countries' at line 1

Any ideas?

Comment: It seems the production server doesn't have a version that supports window functions

Comment: And what versions of the database server are running on the live server. PHP will not be effecting this

Comment: You might find it more reliable to set your test (local) environment up with the same versions of the same software as the live target environment :)

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos can you suggest an alternative on dense_rank? I will contact my provider to ask if they can add support to window functions.

RiggsFolly indeed the live server runs on a different version of db (i added to the original question), which is percona.

I will try setting up percona locally to see if this is the issue.

Comment: Window functions where introduced in [MariaDB 10.2.0](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/window-functions/). So it is definitely a DB Server version issue. Perhaps you can use variables to simulate `DENSE_RANK`.

Comment: Totally agree with RiggsFolly. It's a good idea to make sure you use the same versions of _all_ software in development that you will eventually use when you deploy to production. That includes database, web server, programming language, application framework, etc. Otherwise you are bound to get surprises like this.

Comment: Also keep in mind that MariaDB is a fork of MySQL circa 2010. After that, the products have been gradually diverging. It's now 2021, and we should stop thinking of MariaDB as compatible with MySQL. They have too many differences in features. Whereas Percona Server is a _branch_ of MySQL, not a fork. Percona continues to rebase to every release of MySQL, so they will continue to be compatible.

Comment: An update one this. After opening a ticket with my provider, they are still running on version 5.6 with a plan to update to 5.7 soon but no mysql 8 so window functions are not available. As a result I will have to either change my implementation or move to another service. Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first comment was the correct answer "It seems the production server doesn't have a version that supports window functions" After contacting my provider it seems that they still use older versions of MySQL without window functions, thus I will have to change the implementation of ranking system.